# CSS hover stops working after using a JavaScript function to display different span

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a group of spans with corresponding labels. I want to always be able to hover over a label and see the corresponding picture.

In CSS I have:

```
<style>
td:hover span {
    display: block;
}
</style>
```

My spans look roughly like:

```
<td><label>firstLabel</label>
<span id="image1" class="first_image_span" style="display:block" >
<img src="image1.jpg"></span></td>


<td><label>secondLabel</label>
<span id="image2" class="second_image_span">
<img src="image2.jpg"></span></td>

<td><label>thirdLabel</label>
<span id="image3" class="third_image_span">
<img src="image2.jpg"></span></td>
```

If this was the only code I had, it would work perfectly fine. The problem is that I had to add buttons to navigate the pictures manually. The problem is that once I show span 2 , the hover over stops working on span 1. When I go to span 3, the hover over stops working for span 1, and 2. Is there anything I can do? My JavaScript function roughly works like this:

```
function changeImage(count) {
  document.getElementById(functionSpanName.toString() + slideCounter.toString()).removeAttribute("style");

  slidecounter += count;

document.getElementById(functionSpanName.toString() + slideCounter.toString()).style.display = "block";
}
```

At first I thought the problem was that it wasn't working because there was no style.. but at the start of the pageload, the first span is the only span to have a style and all the other hovers work on the other spans. Also replacing the remove attribute with a style.display = "none" doesn't work since it means that the spans will permanently not display.

Comment: What makes the spans hidden in the first place so the hover will show them?

Comment: Hover only works on the top span, you can adjust z-index to change which span is highest. Also you can use js to activate hover on another span (say span 1) when when you are hovering the top most span (say span 3)

Comment: @jcsanyi The first span has the display:block which displays the span. The other spans don't have this inline style. When you click the forward image button it removes the current inline style from span one and puts span 2 as display:block

Comment: @user2593801 but what's stopping the spans that don't have `display:block` from being displayed? By default, spans have `display:inline`, which would still show up just fine.

Comment: Good question. I think because all the spans are "stacked" on top of each other the span with the style="display:block" is the only one shown because it's "on top". In fact when I make say both span 1 and span 2 have the display:block, span 1 will never be shown at all and will be overridden by span 2 (although span 3 will still have the hover over ability still working)

Comment: @SethMcClaine Could you give me an example of what you mean by changing the z index? how would that affect the hover? Also do you mean add a mouseover event manually somewhere with js? I tried to go that route but I wasn't able to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than messing with manually adding and removing a style, why not just add or remove a class to indicate the selected item.

Something like this:

```css
td span {
    display: none;
}
td span.current, td:hover span {
    display: block;
}
```

And then change your function like this:

```js
function changeImage(count) {
    var currId = functionSpanName.toString() + slideCounter.toString();
    document.getElementById(currId).className = '';
    slideCounter += count;
    currId = functionSpanName.toString() + slideCounter.toString();
    document.getElementById(currId).className = 'current';
}
```

Comment: It's the strangest thing. I tried putting your code in and it still has the same problem. The images changed correctly, but still once the image was made visible and then "passed over" and changed back to class = "", the hover over didn't work. So if I cycled from image1 to image3, the hover over wouldn't work for image1 or image2. If I went backwards with the function, the hover over ability came back to all images.